# adding form array values using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

I want to create a form that will add a user input value and a variable value together.

For example, something like this:

```
array 1
value 1 = form.value1
value 2 = form.value2
value 3 = form.value3

array 2
value 1 = 10
value 2 = 20
value 3 = 30

form.answer = array1[i].value * array2[i]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: yes, how do I get the [i] synax to work???

Comment: Do you wish to generate a form from data u have in 2 arrays or do you wish to save the data from the form into javascript objectS?

Comment: a form that will multiply together input values with values from another array, then give the answer in a box on the same form.

Comment: I have amended my example

Comment: Try using this code: 

`var array1 = [4,5,6,7,8,9], array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var  processValues = function() {
    var answer = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            answer += array1[i] * array2[i];
    }
}
`
This will multiply the values from 1 array with values in the other and sum them up in the variable answer.

Comment: Great thanks, this is what i'm looking for! How do I get the answer into a field called form.answer.value?

Comment: Editing your question and adding supplementary code is preferred over "answering" your question with additional requested code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
var array1 = [4,5,6,7,8,9], array2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; 
var processValues = function() { 
var answer = null; 
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { 
        //answer += array1[i] * array2[i]; 
        // if your inputs are not numbers or are unparsed form fields
        // cast them into number
        answer += Number(array1[i]) * Number(array2[i]);             
    }
}
```

This will multiply the values from 1 array with values in the other and sum them up in the variable answer.
In array1 store the values that you have read from the form and in array2 the values u need to multiply them with.

Edit: Updated answer based on your code

You missed a few things in your code:

1] Your click handler for calculate totals doesnt have the form as argument.

```
     <input name="Calculate Total" type="button" id="Calculate Total" value="Calculate Total" onclick="Calc_totals(form);" />
```

2] Your variables are not in scope in the calc_totals function
use the following script block / optimize it instead

```
var drink = new Array();
var units = new Array();
function Calc(form) {


    drink [0] = form.drink0.value;
    drink [1] = form.drink1.value;
    drink [2] = form.drink2.value;


    units [0] = 25;
    units [1] = 50;
    units [2] = 75;

    var number_units = new Array()
    form.units0.value = form.drink0.value * units[0];
    form.units1.value = form.drink1.value * units[1];
    form.units2.value = form.drink2.value * units[2]; 
}    
function Calc_totals(form) {
    var answerValue = 0; 
    for(i=0; i < units.length; i++) { 
    answerValue += Number(drink[i]) * Number(units[i]);
    } 
    form.total_units.value = answerValue;
}
```

As you can see the last line reads form.total_units.value wich is where you want to add the units and not form.answer.value since there is no input field with the id as answer.

Comment: How do I get the answer into a field called form.answer.value?

Comment: You can get the answer into a field using the following code `document.forms["form1"].answer.value = answer;`

Comment: OK, so here's my actual code:

    function Calc_totals() { 
      
       var drink = new Array()
       drink [0] = form.drink0.value;
     
     var units = new Array()
     units [0] = 25;    
     
     
        for (i = 0; i < units.length; i++) { 
            form.answer.value += (drink[i]) * (units[i]);                         
        }
     
    }
    </script>

Answer isn't working. What am I mssing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure what you are asking, maybe this?

```
<form>
<select id="choose_month">
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">February</option>
 <option value="3">March</option>
</select>
<select id="choose_year">
 <option value="2010">2010</option>
 <option value="2011">2011</option>
</select>
```

```
function get_answer(){
answer = document.getElementById("choose_month").value + document.getElementById("choose_year").value;
}
```

Comment: No, I simply want to create a form that adds values from an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form name="form1" action="">
       <input name="input1" type="text" value="text1">
       <input name="input2" type="text" value="text2">
    </form>

    <script>
       var arr1 = document.forms['form1'];
       var arr2 = [34, 567];
       alert(arr1[0].value+arr2[1]);

//Edited
       var sum = 0;            
       for(i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
          sum += parseInt(arr1[i])*parseInt(arr2[i].value);
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to multiply the value from input 1 with a value from array 2. There will be multiple values in each array. All I want to do is calculate the total. Is this a loop using [i]?

Comment: @dmvlpr—the result will be the concatenation of the two values, since the value of a form control is always a string.

Comment: so with `parseInt` you can multiply the value of input[i] with value of array2[i]..